# Is it OK to include files using ABSPATH?

Tags: functions

I was using the following: `get_home_path();` in my functions.php as referenced [in the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path) – but I get the error:

```
Call to undefined function get_home_path() in ...
```

I'd like to include a file using it. I noticed there is also the constant `ABSPATH`. Is there any reason I shouldn't just use `ABSPATH` as an alternative to `get_home_path()`?

#### Edit

I am using it as so (this is crazy simple) – in my functions.php file at the start of the file I have put:

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php' );
```

If I put:

```
$path = get_home_path();
require_once( $path . 'vendor/autoload.php' );
```

That's when it all goes wrong, with the generic error about the function not being available.

Comment: What is your exact usecase. I cannot really guess why you would get the error you are getting. Also, `ABSPATH` is used by `get_home_path()` if you look at the source code

Comment: I'm using composer to install some dependencies of my Wordpress install.

Comment: Shouldn't you be working within your theme folder? So have composer & vendor set up inside `wp-content/themes/your-theme`

Answer (score 1):

[`get_home_path()` only works when WP admin scripts are loaded.](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path)

`ABSPATH` is [defined in wp-config.php](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-config-sample.php#L84) so works anytime after the config file is loaded, so it should be totally fine for your use.

It is set to the `dirname(__FILE__) + trailing slash` of wp-load.php (same location as e.g. wp-config.php). `dirname` here returns the absolute path where WordPress is installed. For example, `/home/user/public_html` and `ABSPATH` adds a trailing slash

```
/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

// So,
ABSPATH == '/home/user/public_html/'; // WP files are in public_html
```

So if you have a folder structure such as this:

```
- public_html/
- - wp-admin/
- - wp-content/
- - wp-includes/
- - wp-config.php
- - wp-load.php
- - vendor/
- - - autoload.php
- ...
```

You can put the following in your theme's functions.php file to load the autoload.php file

```
require_once( ABSPATH . 'vendor/autoload.php' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this issue is that `get_home_path()` can only be used in the admin?
As it says in small letters in [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_home_path):

> This is a backend function.